# Font color is not the same after exporting to pdf in LibreOffice

Tags: colors, libreoffice-writer, print-to-pdf

Is it possible to make exported pdf files look like odt files ? For some reason entire text is being transformed to black font. Thank you.

Comment: Just to make sure i've understood the problem correctly: The generated PDF has the same font and everything else like the odt, just the font color is changed to black - is this right? Additionally, i assume you've used the "Export as PDF" feature to create the PDf. There are other ways to create a PDF from LO, e.g. using a "PDF Printer".

Answer (score 2):

Check the print options. There's an option to print all text in black; **make sure to disable this option**. Now, exporting colored text to PDF should work.

The print options are available using Menu "`Tools`" -> "`Options`" -> "`LibreOffice Writer`" -> "`Print`":

[image]

Comment: there must me a bug in Writer becasue this doesn't work for me

Comment: @banuy: hmm - that's strange. Wich LO version are you using? Would it be possible to provide both a odt example document and the generated PDF, so i could try to reproduce the issue? I've tested it myself successfully with LO 4.2.4.2 on Linux Mint 17.

Comment: "generated PDF has the same font and everything else like the odt, just the font color is changed to black" - exactly. Method I'm using is "Export as PDF". The version of LO is 4.2.5.2. I also tried through PDF printer: file - print - options - print to file, but font always change to black.

Comment: Sorry, then i can't help with this - there's no other option besides "`Print text in black`" that may cause such a behaviour. Could you provide a screenshot of the Options -> LibreOffice Writer -> Print Options?

Comment: few screenshots: [link](http://i.imgur.com/ZKXnpmN.png)

Comment: Sorry, i've tried your settings both with windows and linux, but i couldn't reproduce that issue. Text is colored in the resulting PDF. So, i can't help any further.

Answer (score 1):

In the [screenshot images you posted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eef0p.png), you have the "Convert colors to greyscale" option selected. Try disabling this option. The color font you are using may convert to something close to black when converted to greyscale.

Comment: Welcome to Super User.  The poster hasn't been back since asking the question 3 yrs ago, so we may never know the issue for sure.  However, this was a great catch and probably correct, so +1.

Answer (score 0):

Ok! 3 years after! I found out that I could solve this issue by selecting all the text in the document and manually setting the color to white. It was on "automatic by default, so maybe the Pdf conversion has some issues with it! Hope it helps other people!